# Selecting a table and setting a value in it in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, set

I am trying to write a script that archives a user by setting the value of the archive column to the value of 1 . I have written the following script to do this, but I am not sure if I am using the syntax correctly as I am am getting the following error.

```
<?php
mysql_query("SELECT FROM archive hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead
             WHERE cf_uid = '{cf_uid}'
             SET archive='1';"
) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

The error I am getting is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server     version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE cf_uid = 'c68235f3fb5c3f7fff6247b04c450dd7'     SET archive='1'' at line 1

Comment: if I add SELECT FROM, I still get : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM archive hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE cf_uid = 'c68235f3fb5c3f' at line 1

Comment: The syntax is `SELECT [list of fields] FROM [table name] WHERE [conditions]`. Also, if you're trying to update a table, you should use `UPDATE` instead of `SELECT`. This is pretty basic stuff, I suggest you go back to a book or a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `SET` in a `SELECT` statement, and you're missing the `FROM` part.

You need an `UPDATE` command, perhaps like:

```
UPDATE archive SET archive='1' WHERE cf_uid = '$cf_uid'
```

Comment: Hi, the table name isn't archive though, the column is archive, I am trying the following but am getting an error : UPDATE hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead SET archive='1' WHERE cf_uid = '{cf_uid}';

Comment: it gives me Unknown column 'archive' in 'field list'

Comment: ahh sorted it now, its called archived not archive

Answer (score 2):

`UPDATE archive`, not `SELECT archive`. Also, you're inviting a visit from [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: I didnt realise you had to sanitise bracketed things, I thought it was only GET and POST, do you sanitise them in the same way ?